# What do sentences in the theory of the structure $A=(Q,<,n)_{n \in N}$ look like?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, formal-languages

I'm working on a problem from Kees Doets, and he mentions the following structures:

$X=(Q,<,n)_{n \in N}$

$Y=(Q,<,\frac{-1}{n+1})_{n \in N}$

$Z=(Q,<,q_n)_{n \in N}$ where $\{q_n\}_{n \in N}$ is an ascending sequence of rationals converging to some irrational.

The problem asks to show that up to isomorphism $Y$ and $Z$ are the only other countable models of $Th(X)$. Also asks to show which one is saturated and which one is prime. But for now I have a much more basic question:

What does a sentence in $Th(X)$ look like? I am confused by the symbols $n \in N$ added to the language. Can a sentence $\phi \in Th(X)$ for example be $\phi=\forall q \in Q, \exists n \in N: q<n$

This is true in the rationals, but is a sentence allowed to quantify over the constant symbols in its language, or is quantification reserved only for variables which will be interpreted in the model? Assuming of course that the interpretation of the symbols $n$ in the model is actually the natural numbers.

Comment: "Is a sentence allowed to quantify over the constant symbols in its language?" No. "Is quantification reserved only for variables which will be interpreted in the model?" Yes. That's how quantifiers work in first-order logic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Hmm, so the sentence $\phi$ I have written above is not actually a sentence in $Th(X)$.

Comment: Correct, it's not even a well-formed sentence. (And if it were, $Y$ and $Z$ wouldn't be models of $\text{Th}(X)$!)

Comment: @AlexKruckman

Is it not well-formed because it quantifies over constant symbols, or is there some other reason?

How about the sentence: $\phi= q_1<10 \Rightarrow \exists q_2 \in Q: q_1<q_2$

Comment: That's also not a sentence, because $q_1$ is a free variable. It is a well-formed *formula*, although I would write it as $((q_1 < 10)\rightarrow \exists q_2\, (q_1<q_2))$.

Comment: Quantifiers in first-order logic usually are just written $\forall x$ or $\exists x$, not $\forall x\in Q$. The exception is when you're working with multi-sorted first-order logic, where you may see quantifiers that look like $(\forall x\in S)$. But here $S$ is required to be a sort symbol in the vocabulary (and the set of constant symbols is not a sort symbol). Of course, different authors may use different notational conventions. I'm not familiar with the book by Kees Doets that you're reading.

Comment: @AlexKruckman My bad, forgot to add the universal quantifier, hopefully when I do then this becomes a sentence in $Th(X)$:

$\forall q_1 (q_1<10) \Rightarrow \exists q_2 (q_1<q_2)$

Comment: Yep, now that's a sentence!

Comment: The idea is that the language is the same for all three structures, namely the 2 place relation symbol < and an infinite list of constant symbols, say a1, a2, a3, ... The 3 structures are all models of the complete theory consisting of Dense Linear Ordering axioms plus the infinite list a1 < a2, a2 < a3, .... and so they are elementarily equivalent but not isomorphic, which is the point of the example. So the sentences of the language don't include names for specific rational numbers or integers but rather the common constant symbols which are interpreted differently in the three models.

Comment: @Ned Thank you, I will post a separate question about this!